# How to have different seeders depending on the language selected in Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.4, seed

So I am developing under Laravel 5.4 And I need to seed the database with different values according to current language selected by the user.

For the translation I am using a JQuery plugin which return the value

```
var global_lang = "fr"; //if french
```

and

```
var global_lang = "en"; //if english
```

I want my Laravel seeder to look like the following :

```
public function run()
{
    $this->call(CommonTimerSeeder::class);

    switch(config('global_lang')) {
        case 'en' :
            $this->call(EnglishSeeder::class);
            break;

        case 'fr' :
            $this->call(FrenchSeeder::class);
            break;
    }
}
```

But I don't know if this is possible to get the value of global_lang which is a JS value, and I am wondering because I want to change seeders depending on the language selected so this is a bad idea cause the seeders are in php (mean server-side)

Do you have any idea ? Maybe a better way to achieve my goal ?
Thank you and don't hesitate to ask me if i'm not enough clear on some points,

regards,

Comment: what is the purpose of changing the seeders depending on each session of the browser? you can even have multiple people using the platform at the same time with different languages. Can you please explain the reason to run different seeders?

Comment: Are you using the standard method of getting the locale, meaning `App::getLocale();`? The translation part should be determined in the backend to begin with. It's not very clear where that happens from your question.

Comment: @SérgioReis Reis My objective is to change the seeders depending on the language selected because my seeder contain french sentances and I am not able to translate them because they are not in a blade.php file, they are located into the seeder

Comment: @Andrew, I am sorry I don't understand your sentance, I think it probably mean that the answer is no, I understand the question isn't clear because it isn't even for me and I'm sorry about it

Comment: But the seeders insert to the database right? you should run all of them and then, depending on your selected language, fetch what you need. Also, laravel has a built-in translation feature. check https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/localization#introduction

Comment: Of course yes, I solved the problem by changing the text once the data is loaded and not depending on the seeders, I run all french seeders and then I change the text depending on the selected language by the Used
Thank you, I already know this feature from laravel but the point is that I wanted a client-side translation which I cannot resolve using php

|| _edit: I will post the solution below thank your for you help :)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found to solve the problem:

I souldn't use the seeders because the only utility to seeders is to insert data into the database.

So I find how to translate data, I let the seeder display french data and then, I used the [Jquery Plugin](https://github.com/tinoni/translate.js) to translate french text in the client side, into english.

Here is a exemple:

```
"text to translate": {
    en: "My english sentence",
    fr: "Ma phrase française"
}
```

So my problem had no relations with seeders, you should not modify seeders which are server-side if you want a client-side translation.